# How To Select DropDown Menu Items of webbrowser? Visual Basic 2008 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox, html-select

Hello to all my friends and readers.
I'm creating an application in which I need to select an option of combobox/dropdown list of Webbrowser.
actually the work of my program is that it should comment (send/submit Text) anonymously to my blogspot page (a hidden page).
I will use this method in my other programs for send feed back to me.
I don't want to use email service because some antivirus can detect it and may be some experts may hack My email password. So I decided to use this method.

My problem is that blogger comment box selected item is "google account" or "select an option"
I want to change the selected item to "ANONYMOUSLY".
I have Googled and have tried many Codes samples. But :-(

Here Is My Code:

```
Public Class Form1

 Dim pagepathh As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\sample.htm"
Dim posturl As String = "<iframe allowtransparency=""true"" class=""blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post"" frameborder=""0"" height=""234px"" id=""comment-editor"" name=""comment-editor"" src=""http://www.blogger.com/comment-iframe.g?blogID=8713182853230782541&amp;pageID=4831696032518082948&amp;blogspotRpcToken=9354446#%7B%22color%22%3A%22rgb(255%2C%20255%2C%20255)%22%2C%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22rgb(20%2C%2020%2C%2020)%22%2C%22unvisitedLinkColor%22%3A%22rgb(136%2C%20136%2C%20136)%22%2C%22fontFamily%22%3A%22Arial%2C%20Tahoma%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20FreeSans%2C%20sans-serif%22%7D"" width=""100%""></iframe>"
'This Is Bloger Comment Body Url.
```

Form1 Load:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(pagepathh, posturl, False)
    wb1.Navigate(pagepathh) 'WB1 is my webbrowser.
```

Button1 (Post Button) Click:

```
wb1.Document.GetElementById("commentBodyField").SetAttribute("Value", tb_comment.Text) ' tb_Comment is comment textbox.
```

`I want To Place Some Code Here To Set Combobox Selected Item "anonymously".`

```
    wb1.Document.GetElementById("postCommentSubmit").InvokeMember("click")
```

Here Is Blogspot Dropdown list HTML Codes:

```
<select id="identityMenu" name="identityMenu" dir="ltr" onchange="BLOG_CMT_onSelectorChange()" style="display: inline; ">
<option value="NONE" disabled="">Select profile...</option>
<option value="NONE" disabled=""> </option>
<option value="GOOGLE">Google Account</option>
<option value="NONE">LiveJournal</option>
<option value="NONE">WordPress</option>
<option value="NONE">TypePad</option>
<option value="NONE">AIM</option>
<option value="OPENID">OpenID</option>
<option value="NONE" disabled=""> </option>
<option value="NAMEURL">Name/URL</option>
<option value="ANON">Anonymous</option>
```

Additional Information:

```
Platform: Visual Basic Express 2010
.Net Framework is 2.0
Webpage Dropdown List Id: "identityMenu"
Webpage Button Submit Id: "postCommentSubmit"
Webpage Comment Textbox Id: "commentBodyField"
```

Please Really Really Sorry For My Bad English Spell And Grammatical Mistakes.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks to edit! (Tag VBA) Can you please give me the solution of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the id of the select in the HTML which is "identityMenu" then set the "value" attribute to "ANON" which is the value of the Anonymous option you want to select. You can do so with the following code. Hope this helps.

```
wb1.Document.GetElementById("identityMenu").SetAttribute("value","ANON")
```

Comment: Hi @slister, Thank you for your answer but the question has 1 year old and I'm currently on another project that's why I'm not in condition to test your solution.